# How to \clist_set in \msg_new?

Tags: expl3, package-writing, l3keys

Is it possible to process a comma separated list within a LaTeX3 error message?

For example I want to define a message for unknown values to a `.choice` key like in the following example. I use `\test` to generate the error while in the real document it is part of a key definition of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn { test } { unknown-choice } {
   The~value~'#2'~is~not~allowed~for~key~'#1'! \\
   \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #3 }
   Allowed~values:~\clist_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_clist { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~or~ }.
}

\newcommand{\test}{
   \msg_error:nnnnn { test } { unknown-choice }
      { test-key }
      { wrong-value }
      { value-1, value-2, value-3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Test Document \test
\end{document}
```

But this gives me this message:

```
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !
 ! test error: "unknown-choice"
 ! 
 ! The value 'wrong-value' is not allowed for key 'test-key'!
 ! \clist_set:Nn {value-1,value-2,value-3}Allowed values: .
 ! 
 ! See the test documentation for further information.
 ! 
 ! Type <return> to continue.
 !..........................................…..
```

As you can see `\clist_set` is printed verbatim instead of being expanded.

Comment: Messages are implemented with `\write` where assignments are not performed. All `\<module>_set:<signature>` functions are not expandable (and protected).

Comment: So there’s no way to process such a list in a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way: set the `\l_tmpa_clist` before calling the error message but this feels “wrong” …

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn { test } { unknown-choice } {
   The~value~'#2'~is~not~allowed~for~key~'#1'! \\
   Allowed~values:~\clist_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_clist { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~or~ }.
}

\newcommand{\test}{
   \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { value-1, value-2, value-3 }
   \msg_error:nnnn { test } { unknown-choice }
      { test-key }
      { wrong-value }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Test Document \test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why should it be wrong? I'm not sure what you're about, though.

Comment: It feels wrong to pass the variable in that way since it is not an argument to `\msg_error` then. Passing `\l_tmpa_clist` as `{ #3 }` didn’t work …

Comment: Is this a typo? `\msg_error:nnnnn` has five arguments but you only give it four…

Comment: @clemens: Nope … the command is available with two to six arguments, where the first two specify the module and the message and the last (zero to four) can be used to pass text to the message, see `source3.pdf` (from p. 151)

Comment: @clemens: Ops. Now I see what you mean … jep this is a typo …